# Invalid hexadecimal character when fetching RSS feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I use the below code to get an RSS feed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string x = "https://www.bezaat.com/ksa/jeddah/rss/187";
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(x);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["item"];
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

But I get this error:

> '', hexadecimal value 0x08, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 17857.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: 0x08 is backspace I think in Ascii & Unicode

Comment: Can you give a stacktrace? There is no column 17857 in the url you've provided.

Comment: @CommuSoft it also moved by 1523 characters between the question title and question body! (but, yeah, source is 12469 characters at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the XML document is malformed. You should reject it, and report it to the owner if it has invalid characters. Your other option (which I don't recommend) is using a regex function and filtering out the malformed characters. Get a list of all invalid characters you are having an issue with, and using regex, strip out those characters.